# write to a new line in a json file (Python)

Tags: python, json

Hi I have a loop that outputs

```
for i in item : 
     print(i)

output : 
{'test1' : '1'}
{'test2' : '2'} 
...
```

I want to save everything to a new .json file keeping the format. i.e. I have to open the json file to write line by line. When I open the new json file, it has to be a file with each line containing the output of print(i)

```
json file :

{'test1' : '1'}
{'test2' : '2'}
```

May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json

item = [{'test1' : '1'},{'test2' : '2'}]

with open("new.json", "w")as file:
    json.dump(fp=file, indent=4, obj=item)
```